# How use values mode in Orion?

Tags: fiware-orion

Reading FIWARE-NGSI v2 Specification  (http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/latest/)

In section Simplified Entity Representation
I couldn't test values mode as recomend. My test fail:

> values mode. This mode represents the entity as an array of attribute
>   values. Information about id and type is left out. See example below.
>   The order of the attributes in the array is specified by the attrs URI
>   param (e.g. attrs=branch,colour,engine). If attrs is not used, the
>   order is arbitrary.
>
> [ 'Ford', 'black', 78.3 ]

Where and how I referenced an entityID?

```
POST /v2/entities/Room1?options=values&attrs=branch,colour,engine
```

payload:

```
[ 'Ford', 'black', 78.3 ]
```

Answer:

```
{
    "error": "MethodNotAllowed",
    "description": "method not allowed"
}
```

POST /v2/entities?options=values

payload:

```
[ 'Ford', 'black', 78.3 ]
```

Answer:

```
{
    "error": "ParseError",
    "description": "Errors found in incoming JSON buffer"
}
```

Version:
GET /version

```
{
    "orion": {
        "version": "1.10.0-next",
        "uptime": "0 d, 0 h, 1 m, 34 s",
        "git_hash": "0f92803495a8b6c145547e19f35e8f633dec92e0",
        "compile_time": "Fri Feb 2 09:45:41 UTC 2018",
        "compiled_by": "root",
        "compiled_in": "77ff7f334a88",
        "release_date": "Fri Feb 2 09:45:41 UTC 2018",
        "doc": "https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/master/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"options=values" is a representation format for querying data not for posting new entity data for obvious reasons, when you are creating new entities you have to specify the entity id and the entity type and with the values representation format you can't ...

Comment: Maybe NGSIv2 spec should be more explicit regarding the usage of values mode only for get operations. I've opened an issue about it: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3098

Comment: I understood that the action was to create entities. The same example with keyValues is possible (with POST). But was a GET request.